# How do I compare explanatory power of Dirichlet regression with other models?

Tags: compositional-data, dirichlet-regression

I have a dataset with 7 variables expressed in % of the total (i.e. one of the constraints is that sum of the variables = 100%).

I am looking at **Dirichlet regression** in R for the first time (I am getting some help with this).  I would like to compare the results and explanatory power of the Dirichlet regression with the OLS regression (also possibly with a Isometric Log-Ratio centred transformation).

I would ideally want to compare the R2 value of the model but I don't seen to be able to find one for the Dirichlet regression.  Is there something else that can be used to compare the explanatory power of the models?

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand-side variables in Dirichlet and OLS are distinct, just like those in  binary logit regression and linear probability models. Therefore, common statistics reported by the model output, such as AIC, log likelihood, some psuedo-R2 are not comparable.

You need to compare predicted proportions with original observations. Use `predict()` for the Dirichlet regression model to find the predicted proportions. Use `predict()` and then `ilrInv()` for OLS based on ilr transformation.

You can find R2 by squaring the correlation between the predicted proportions and original observations. Since there are seven proportions, you can calculate seven category-specific R2 and one overall R2. You can also use other measures, such as RMSE. You can visualize the results in a scatter plot of predicted proportions over original observations, color by category and shape by model.

On another note, comparing proportions directly may not be desired, as a predicted deviation by 5% for an observed 50% seems fine but for an observed 1% may be catastrophic. Therefore, comparing proportions on a transformed scale may be safer. Since proportions are ranged between zero and one, a logit transformation seems good as a one-to-one mapping, `logit(p) = ln(p/(1-p)`. Showing R2, RMSE, and scatter plot of predicted vs. observed logit(p) should be also considered.

After applying appropriate transformation of the predicted response, you can also compare average marginal effects of predictors on predicted proportions. This can be done by the package `marginaleffects`.